# How to find someone elses Post ID from an Ad ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Companies like bigspy are able to find the Post ID from an Ad ID without having the access token.

How is that possible?

For example this user hides posts, only the Ad ID is visible:

[https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&q=Phil%20Speiser&sort_data[direction]=desc&sort_data[mode]=relevancy_monthly_grouped&search_type=keyword_unordered&media_type=all](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&q=Phil%20Speiser&sort_data%5Bdirection%5D=desc&sort_data%5Bmode%5D=relevancy_monthly_grouped&search_type=keyword_unordered&media_type=all)

This is an example how a post looks like, this isn't visible in his profile (hidden post):

https://www.facebook.com/spyzrmusic/posts/pfbid0gcSsDiVrr89bp1xYzq8D4HGkAkhahaRCunQUanR9NYiHMYDPBtW14r1wvfJEA1Nml

Answer (score 0):

bigspy and any other AdSpy using users data to collect ads,
like if I have some kind of chrome extension that sees all my Facebook home page posts and ads they are able to get the details based on this method and then them to their database, there is no way you can get original ad copy from just the ad library id, because of security reasons.